# Python : IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

```
#Returns the sum of num1 and num2
while True:
  def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
  def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

  def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

  def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

#*, -, /, +
#remember brackets work like normal
  def main ():
    operation = input("What type of calculation would you like to make? +,-,/,*")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*'):
    #operation invalid
      print("To continue enter a vaild operation")
    else:
      var1 = int(input("Enter num1:"))
      var2 = int(input("Enter num1:"))
      if(operation == '+'):
        print(add(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '/'):
        print(div(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '*'):
        print(mul(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '-'):
        print(sub(var1, var2))
       #Restarts the calculator
    while True:
        answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print ("Invalid input.")
    if answer == "y":
 continue
    else:
        print ('Goodbye')
        break
main(add)
```

Hi, beginner here. I am getting `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. Any help would be nice. If I put the continue down any further, I get `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Not sure what to do.

Comment: What's that `continue` doing hanging out way back behind the preceding `if`?

Comment: What is the exact error , can you copy-paste the whole error message as it also has a line no. ?

Comment: You are using the continue statement in the wrong place but there are some other serious issues with your code.  Think about the logic behind if answer in ('y','n'):  and then break so if the answer is y or n then you are going to break from the loop

Comment: So uh, are you familiar with how Python indentation works? "Move things around until the code compiles" will cause you a lot of frustration.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no I am not i am just starting off.

Comment: Then you should read some kind of tutorial (like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)), or your experience with Python will be slow and painful, which would be a shame because it's quite a nice system.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 i'll look at it in a bit i am going out for dinner

Answer (score 0):

I got it on

```
File "", line 24
    continue
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Your function should be like the below

```
def main ():
    operation = input("What type of calculation would you like to make? +,-,/,*")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*'):
    #operation invalid
      print("To continue enter a vaild operation")
    else:
      var1 = int(input("Enter num1:"))
      var2 = int(input("Enter num1:"))
      if(operation == '+'):
        print(add(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '/'):
        print(div(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '*'):
        print(mul(var1, var2))
      elif(operation == '-'):
        print(sub(var1, var2))
       #Restarts the calculator
    while True:
        answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print ("Invalid input.")
        if answer == "y":
            continue
        else:
            print ('Goodbye')
            break
```

Comment: when i try to run it says NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`

From http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Thanks @Rajarshit Das the code runs but the script doesnt run again after you input y (not being sarcastic)

Answer (score -1):

There were numerous misaligned chunks of code that I corrected for you. Also corrected other errors as well. Try to avoid `while True:` loops altogether as your program can easily get stuck in one and cause unintended consequences.

```
# Returns the sum of num1 and num2

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2


def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2


# *, -, /, +
# remember brackets work like normal
def main():
    operation = raw_input("What type of calculation would you like to make? +,-,/,*")
    if (operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*'):
        # operation invalid
        print("To continue enter a vaild operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(raw_input("Enter num1:"))
        var2 = int(raw_input("Enter num1:"))
        if (operation == '+'):
            print(add(var1, var2))
        elif (operation == '/'):
            print(div(var1, var2))
        elif (operation == '*'):
            print(mul(var1, var2))
        elif (operation == '-'):
            print(sub(var1, var2))
    # Restarts the calculator

main()
answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
while answer == "y":
    main()
    answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
```

Comment: "the `while True:` containing functions is illegal" - according to whom? "Functions and Classes have to be on the most outer left as they are their own entity." - Also no. Heck, if you couldn't put a function anywhere but the outermost indentation level, how would you define class methods?

Comment: True but try to run the program with that `while True` containing functions and see if you can get it to run....

Comment: Just because it wasn't implemented properly doesn't mean it's "illegal" or that functions and classes "have to be" at the outermost indentation level.

Comment: Thank you for the help just trying to learn the basics and get started!

Comment: @HoneyCentaur not a problem! Don't forget to accept the correct answer please!

Comment: when I try running it says NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Ok I havent had any work for me maybe im doing something wrong, not sure.

Comment: @HoneyCentaur switch raw_input to just input

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs due to bad indentation. In Python, bad indentation means odd number of spaces. For example, 0, 1 or 3 spaces is bad indentation.

For example

```
def main():
    pass
```

Is valid indentation, as the statement `pass` under `main` function is having 4 spaces; instead if the statement `pass` is having 0, 1 or 3 spaces under `main`. Valid indentation includes even number of spaces 2, 4 etc.

Well, in short, indentation in Python should be 2 or 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks I'll remember that